# Replacing a modal view

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Setting:**

The first view controller for my app is `PostsViewController`. In `viewDidLoad` I check if the user is logged in, and if not I preset `SignupVC` modally. There is an option to login instead of signup of course, and I want to replace the signup VC with a login VC.

I tried making a "show detail (replace)" segue from signup to login VC, but that seemed to present login modal on top of signup VC. The problem with it is after the user is logged in, I have two modals to close, and it seems tricky to close both of them at the same time. Ideally, I want to replace the signup VC with the login VC and only close one modal.

**Q1.** How come the `show detail` segue works like `present modally` segue when applied to a modal view controller?

**Q2.** How can I replace the SignUp View controller with a login View controller?

Comment: So do you want SignupVC to show and then the LoginVC or do you just want to present the LoginVC only? its not clear what the flow of the UI is here.

Comment: Signup will show up first. In Signup VC, there is a button that the user can click to go to login VC. In login VC, there is a button to go back to signUp VC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right so after rereading your question and your comment it's clear what you're trying to do here.

**Q1:** Because you can only present a `viewController` `modally` on parent / child views that are `modally` presented. You cannot push a new `viewController` onto a `modally` presented `viewController`. In order to push a `viewController` you need a `UINavigationController` in the view hierarchy (Normally the parent / root view)

**Q2:** You'll need to present it modally from the signupVC.

Example:

```
//Somewhere in SingupVC
[self presentViewController:LoginVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Edit**

To answer your question in the comments:

No there really isn't a way to dismiss both VC's at the same time.

However there are a couple of ways to do it almost:

You can set a `boolean` flag on `SingupVC` that `LoginVC` was presented. That way, when `viewWill/Did appear` is called on `singupVC` and the `boolean` flag is set to `YES` you can call: `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];`

And that way both VCs are dismissed. One when the user dismisses `LoginVC` via the back button and `SingupVC` via a if statement in one of the view life cycle methods (if loginVCPresent) dismiss view, type of thing.

Comment: This is one of the methods I tried and the problem with this is there's no way to close two modals (signUpVC and loginVC) simultaneously.